# What's the basic difference in UIAutomation (Instruments) and PerfectoMobile Testing (iOS)

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation

I am trying to find out if i can use UIAutomation (Instruments) for all my automation need. So far one of the show stopper i see is, UIAutomation is unable to switch the application while my application require to share a document between two application. Guys - What's the basic approach differentiation between UIAutomation & PefectoMobile.

BTW, I can switch between applications using Pefecto Mobile solution.

Thanks & Regards -

Comment: If you look for automation solution that enables you to switch applications, take a look at [SeeTest](http://experitest.com/) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perfecto Mobile is for testers that won't probably see the code, for example. They have access to devices that have the app/apps. From there, they will create automated scripts that will then perform almost the same thing as UI automation. The thing is that with UI Automation, you have to give accessibility to your elements in order to test something. I would say that UI Automation has a better performance overall. Think of it in this way:

**UI Automation** - Developers or persons that will have a closer relationship with the code.

**Perfecto Mobile** - Testers, that sometimes don't even know how iOS works internally. This is useful when you want to really separate things: developers develop, and testers test it.

Separating things is good, because a tester that never seen code, or how the app is suppose to work, gives a fresh perspective to the project. You can also argue that, normally, a tester ( a person that tests for living) will do a better job a testing than a developer.

Comment: I meant application code. You need only accessibility inspector and very basic javascript skills. However, UI Automation is still a terrible framework which doesn't run reliably and sometimes you just wonder what the hell happened.

Comment: Yes but you need to code it... I didn't said you need to do stuff in objective-c (you will probably need for UI Elements made on code and not on Interface Builder). If it's good or not, that's another matter.

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood you.

Comment: No problem Sulthan. ^^

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about PerfectoMobile, but I can answer questions about UI Automation. UI Automation is just a tool, there is no service built behind it like it looks that PerfectoMobile provides. UI Automation comes as part of Apple's developer tools so you don't need to download or license anything else to use it. Once you have tests written in UI Automation, you can use a service like cisimple.com to run them in the cloud as part of a distributed continuous integration process, but that's not set up for you out of the box.

I've written some tutorials on UI Automation that might help you understand what it does so you can make you decision: http://cocoamanifest.net/articles/2011/05/uiautomation-an-introduction.html